# ERROR the set accessor is inaccessible - Deducting user's score as currency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a score manager which tracks down your amount of points. And With these points I want the user to be able to purchase upgrades for his character.

But every time I try to access the user's current score I keep getting the same error message.

If you look at the Upgrademenu Document underneath you can see that I'm trying to do the following   " //  ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost; " The // is there because when I activate it I get the error message:

> The property or indexer 'ScoreManager.Score' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible.

ScoreManager

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreManager Instance { get; private set; }

    public static int Score { get; private set; }

    public int HighScore { get; private set; }

    public bool HasNewHighScore { get; private set; }

    public static event Action<int> ScoreUpdated = delegate {};
    public static event Action<int> HighscoreUpdated = delegate {};

    private const string HIGHSCORE = "HIGHSCORE";
    // key name to store high score in PlayerPrefs

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // Initialize score
        Score = 0;

        // Initialize highscore
        HighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(HIGHSCORE, 0);
        HasNewHighScore = false;
    }

    public void AddScore(int amount)
    {
        Score += amount;

        // Fire event
        ScoreUpdated(Score);

        if (Score > HighScore)
        {
            UpdateHighScore(Score);
            HasNewHighScore = true;
        }
        else
        {
            HasNewHighScore = false;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateHighScore(int newHighScore)
    {
        // Update highscore if player has made a new one
        if (newHighScore > HighScore)
        {
            HighScore = newHighScore;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(HIGHSCORE, HighScore);
            HighscoreUpdated(HighScore);
        }
    }
}
```

UpgradeMenu

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpgradeMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text accuracyText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text speedText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text damageText;

  [SerializeField]
  private Weapon weapon;

  [SerializeField]
  public Projectile projectile;

  [SerializeField]
  private Player player;

  [SerializeField]
  private int upgradeCost = 50;

    void start ()
    {

    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }

    void UpdateValues ()
    {

    }

    public void UpgradeArmor ()
    {
      Health.maxHealth += 2;

    //  ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost;

      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeSouls ()
    {
      EnemySlime.ScoreOnDeath += 1;
      EnemySkeleton.ScoreOnDeath += 1;

    //  ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost;
      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeDamage ()
    {
      Projectile.DamageOnHit += 1;

    //  ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost;

      UpdateValues();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign a value to Score from outside the class if its set accessor is set to private.  Set it to `public` or make a method on the `ScoreManager` class to perform the deduction.

Comment: I understand that, but even when I change my code to  'public static int Score { get; protected set; }' and try to access it from another document. I still get the same error message.

Comment: @mafiaf `protected` is not `public` and won't work.

Comment: I see, by removing the whole "protected" part I don't get the error anymore. But it doesn't seem to deduct the points from the scoreManager.

Comment: @mafiaf That's a separate issue.